# How to change level name using data annotation in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

My code in model is like this:
Inside Employee.cs:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Department")]
    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
```

Inside Department.cs:

```
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

In View Source of the web page, I get:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DepartmentId">DepartmentId</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="DepartmentId" name="DepartmentId"><option 
                 value="1">CSE</option>
                 <option value="2">EEE</option>
                 <option value="3">ME</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DepartmentId" data- 
            valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But in Web page, I get the level name: DepartmentId. I want Department. What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code here looks fully static to make use of the display property you specified in your model you have to make changes as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="DepartmentId" name="DepartmentId"><option 
                 value="1">CSE</option>
                 <option value="2">EEE</option>
                 <option value="3">ME</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DepartmentId" data- 
            valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

note that these changes are not enough you need to send a proper model object to your view and get the model in your view